# Tool to validate domains

Tags: sql, postgresql

Does anyone know a tool that can validate a list of domains(100+ domains) in one run?

Below are the sample list of domains.

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by "validate"?

Answer (score 0):

There the main open source tool designed to validation domain names (validation as correct DNS configuration) is Zonemaster (https://zonemaster.net).

The tool has a "batch mode" that can validate lists of domain names.

You can install it by following the installation instructions on Github: https://github.com/zonemaster/zonemaster

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool called Domain Checker on RapidAPI platform.
You can use this to check the validity of a domain. The tool has a "Batch Request" feature that  can validate a list of domain names. But you have to use the paid version to do that. This tool may be a good solution for your requirement